# what is this general form of an optimization problem (Structural) representing?

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

I am currently reading this article by Sigmund.

> Sigmund, O., Maute, K. Topology optimization approaches. Struct Multidisc Optim 48, 1031–1055 (2013). https://doi.org/10.1007/s00158-013-0978-6

I understand that there are various forms of representation of the general optimization problem and categories such as convex and dual.

In the above text I come across a formulation as follows

\begin{align}
&\min_{\rho}& &F=F(\mathbf{u}(\rho),\rho) = \int_\Omega f(\mathbf{u}(\rho)\, \rho)\, dV\\
&\text{subject to } & &G_0(\rho) = \int_\Omega \rho(\mathbf{x})\, dV - V_0 \leq 0\\
& & &G_i(\mathbf{u}(\rho),\rho)\leq 0,\, i=1, \dots, M\\
& & &\rho(\mathbf{x})=0 \text{ or } 1,\,
\forall \mathbf{x} \in \Omega
\end{align}

with the following text,

> We consider the general topology optimization problem:
> find the material distribution that minimizes an objective
> function F, subject to a volume constraint G0 ≤ 0 and possibly M other constraints Gi ≤ 0, i = 1 ...M. The material
> distribution is described by the density variable ρ(x) that can take either the value 0 (void) or 1 (solid material) at any
> point in the design domain .
> 1 This optimization problem
> can be written in mathematical form as [1] where the state field u satisfies a linear or non-linear state
> equation. For simplicity of later notations, we here assume
> that the objective function can be calculated as the integral
> over a local function f (u(ρ), ρ), as e.g. the strain energy
> density when considering compliance optimization.

From my understanding, $G_0$ is a volume constraint, but the $\int_\Omega \rho(x) dV$ should be giving a representation of the mass. Am I missing a point here?

Comment: I just edited the equations in your question. Please, check that they are correct. Also, it seems that you ask a question in the title of your post and another in the body.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function that you are integrating can take the values 0 or 1, its integral represents the volume. Furthermore, if you think of this function as the mass density it does represent the mass as well.